xml to java class generator, jakarta.xml.bind.annotation
I want to make a spring boot project that converts the XML rules I have into a Java class in the form of "jakarta.xml.bind.annotation". Can I do this by just adding maven dependencies without running xjc process builder?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
